# How to comment the html element dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have the below meta tag,

```
 <meta title='raja' identifier>
```

How do manipulate the dom and it becomes,

```
 <!-- reference <meta title='raja'> -->
```

Please suggest me DOM manipulation than directive.

Thanks,
Raja K

Answer (score 0):

This is raw JavaScript Code, but you could take my function and add it to your Angular Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meta Replace</title>
    <meta title='raja' identifier>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick=replaceWithComment()>Click Me</button>
    <script>
    function replaceWithComment() {
      var metaEl = document.querySelector('meta[identifier]');
      if (metaEl) {
        metaEl.removeAttribute('identifier')
        var commentEl = document.createComment(' reference '+metaEl.outerHTML+' ');
        metaEl.replaceWith(commentEl);
      }
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click on the button the code finds the `<meta>` tag that has the `identifier` attribute. Then it removes the attribute `identifier` and grabs the `outerHTML` of the element and places that along with other text into a new comment.

Then it replaced the `<meta>` tag with the new comment tag.

You may have to change your `querySelector` to find the correct `<meta>` tag.